# passport-jwt verify callback is not triggered

Tags: javascript, passport.js

Playing with passport-jwt, i've been setting up a basic-http endpoint to get my token (using passport-http)

It works.

I want to define my own success|error callbacks using the pattern described in [passport documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Now I want to get passport-jwt working as a middleware for some of my routes as I don't have to repeatedly call passport.authenticate in them.
So I set up this module:

```
var logger = require('../util/logger');
var cfg = require('../cfg');
var router = require('express').Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var User = require('../model/user');


var opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = function(req) {
  var token = null;
  if (req && req.cookies) {
    token = req.cookies.jwt;
  }
  logger.info('jwtFromRequest::token: ' + token); // shown: 'JWT <token_string>''
  return token;
};

opts.secretOrKey = cfg.secret;

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
  logger.info('verify::authenticating request using jwtStrategy'); // not shown
  User.findOne({
    username: jwt_payload.username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      logger.info('verify::error: ' + err); 
      return done(err, false);
    }
    if (user) {
      logger.info('verify::user: ' + user); 
      return done(null, user); 
    } else {
      logger.info('verify: user not found'); 
      return done(null, false);
    }
  });
}));

var Filter = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      var payload = {}
      logger.info("filter::user " + user); // shows false
      if (req.params && req.params.resource) {
        payload.resource = req.params.resource
      }
      payload.message = 'authentication failure'
      return res.status(401).send(payload); // 401 is sent
    } 
    next();

  })(req, res, next);
}

module.exports = Filter;
```

And so goes my route:

```
router.get('/', filter, function(req, res, next) {
  // doing some business
});
```

Despite the fact I'm getting a token, I can't get authentication working (authenticate returns a 401) and I don't get any of my logging instruction in the verify function appended).

According to [passport-jwt source code](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt/blob/master/lib/strategy.js) I feel clueless about that custom jwtFromRequest function beeing called while the verify function is obviously not.

Why does this function end in not being called ?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The issue was I was prepending 'JWT ' to my token as shown in [this tutorial](http://slatepeak.com/guides/building-a-software-as-a-service-saas-startup-pt-2/) which doesn't seem to be required here.